# Introductory Statistics/Probability Reference Request

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I am a PhD student in mathematics with a background in Pure Mathematics. As such I have pretty much zero background in statistics or anything other than the most basic probability (i.e., what one learns in high school). Can anyone recommend good introductory texts for Statistics and Probability which would not be so elementary as to bore me to death?

Comment: I suggest if you can go to the Stats section in your library and browse through a few texts to see which one you find interesting and clear.

Comment: What is your PhD about, so that you need to read about statistics and probability?

Comment: I'd suggest Sheldon Ross' book, though it's at the undergraduate level.

Comment: Casella and Berger's "Statistical Inference" is pretty good. It starts with simple probability, expectation, random variables. Later, it focuses a lot on the statistics side. It is often used in first-year graduate statistics classes.